# Will the size of a java class impact the performance of the application

Tags: java, performance, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

I am doing a swing based application where I use `JTable`. I used `DefaultCellEditor` for one of the column which requires combo box selection. But `DefaultCellEditor` has many methods which I don't require. So I wrote a custom CellEditor by extending `AbstractCellEditor` where I have implemented only the required methods. My question is

(in general) if we have a class and if we don't require all the methods of that class is it fine to use it or is it good to write a custom class where we implement only those methods which we require? and

by using custom class will the performance (memory wise) of the application will be improved or it remains same as the class which has all the methods?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: @guido "premature optimization is the root of all evil" loved it .. :)

Comment: Mathias, are you saying that the JVM doesn't load all the methods of a class - only the ones actually called?  Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz classes are indeed loaded lazily, but not their methods/variables e.t.c

Comment: @guido Thanks. http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization
Its a good article.

Comment: @guido Perfectly apt in this case but you should be aware that that is a partial quotation. The rest of it goes "Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unless you have seriously good grounds for believing that nothing else in the application including the JDK itself uses `DefaultCellEditor,` you are almost certainly wasting your time by making things actively worse.

You also need to consider that you might have saved maybe 100k of code in extreme cases, where typical JVMS use around a gigabyte to execute. So you may have saved 0.01% of code space. This is not a productive use of your time. The correct procedure is to test and measure where the time and space bottlenecks really are, after the fact. Programmers are notoriously poor at predicting these things.

Comment: +1.  Use the `DefaultCellEditor` because you know it's going to work and you won't have introduced any bugs.  Once you're done, profile the system and if the `DefaultCellEditor` appears as a hotspot, _then_ consider customizing or rewriting it.  Optimize last, when you fully understand the problem space and you've got a working solution.

Answer (score 4):

The code (the actual bytecode) for this class is only loaded once, in the PermGen region of memory, regardless of how many objects of this type you instantiate.

I would not accept this code since you are duplicating functionality which is already available, and you're not adding functionality to `AbstractCellEditor`, you're reimplementing code in `DefaultCellEditor` which has already been (hopefully) tested by Oracle (or Sun).

As EJP said, it's not worth the time and potential to introduce bugs.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a custom class which contains fewer member objects, then the memory footprint will be lower.  The number of methods wouldn't impact the size of the objects, just the size of the class.

In general, I would not prematurely optimise unless you determine that you actually have a problem (i.e. if you have thousands of instances of the object and heap/garbage collector log analysis reveals that you're thrashing the memory and/or have frequent of collections of the old space), because additional code means:

- Additional maintenance (you'd need to ensure that your custom `CellEditor` is not buggy)
- Additional effort in writing the custom code
- Additional effort in testing the custom code

AFAIK, a `CellEditor` is instantiated as and when needed, so you wouldn't save much memory anyway.

Comment: Your first sentence is only true if nobody else uses the replaced class, in this case `DefaultCellEditor`, and it doesn't answer the question, which is about methods, not 'member objects'.

Comment: True, but that sort of thing is difficult to measure because of hard references to objects from _other_ objects.  If he passes something in to a constructor that's already referenced somewhere else in the object graph, the shallow footprint might increase but the total memory used doesn't.